# mistake in modal view

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, bootstrap-modal

I am programming in Ruby on Rails 4.2 and Devise.

How I can make sign_in and sign_up views appear in two modal (one modal for each view) using bootstrap ?

Comment: Removed unnecessary texts, but you still need to edit it and post what you have tried and what problem you are facing .

Answer (score -1):

try this...
In Devise, generate multiple model auth:

```
rails generate devise modal1
rails generate devise modal2
rails generate devise modal3
```

It'll generate seperate login forms/ routes for each user types. SO you can easily handle any of customization.